# Segmentation Fault in simple assignment

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, priority-queue

I'm creating a priority queue structure in C.

The struct:

```
#define MAXCOUNT 10
typedef int array[MAXCOUNT+1];

typedef struct {
    int Count;
    array items;
} PriorityQueue;
```

The initialization function:

```
void Initialize(PriorityQueue *PQ)
{
    PQ->Count=0;
}
```

The main:

```
int main (void) {
  PriorityQueue* PQ;
  Initialize(PQ);

  Insert(2, PQ);
  Insert(3, PQ);
  Insert(5, PQ);
  Insert(1, PQ);
  Insert(12, PQ);
  Insert(6, PQ);
  Insert(10, PQ);

  printPQ(PQ);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I run it I get a segmentation fault. Using gdb, I found out that it is thrown on the initialization function. It baffles me how a simple assignment of an `int` could throw a segmentation fault.

Comment: We really need a canonical duplicate for "I try to store stuff through an uninitialized pointer". Would be nice if we could close these very FAQ instantly. I'll looking into cooking up some community wiki.

Comment: Do yourself and everyone a favor: **always** compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: Wow... Thanks for the heads up, but no need to be that harsh mate. Sorry if that question ruined the community, I just thought that SO was a forum and people come to forums mostly due to problems. :/

Comment: Ouch. Is -5 really reasonable? Please don't downvote on grounds of obviousness. This question is clearly posed and well-presented. Plus one.

Answer (score 2):

> *It baffles me how a simple assignment of an `int` could throw a segmentation fault.*

Well, look before that!!!

In your `Initialize()` function, when you're trying to access `PQ`, it is not allocated a *valid* memory. You need to allocate proper memory to `PQ` before dererefencing it. Otherwise, trying to access invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Yes, that was it. I'm terribly sorry for asking such a newbie question, but I was stuck on this segmentation fault for about an hour now. Anyway, best of luck to you.

Comment: @Drunky, if this helped you, please press the button and accept the answer. And consider being stuck on a segfault for just one hour to be a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration:

```
PriorityQueue* PQ;
```

declares a variable (its type and name, and indirectly its position in memory) but does **not** initialize it. So when you pass the value with

```
Initialize(PQ);
```

the called function uses a random value as an address to memory – the assignment

```
PQ->Count=0;
```

puts zero into arbitrary memory location, happily for you into invalid/forbidden location.

Answer (score 0):

Write `PriorityQueue PQ;` instead (i.e. drop the pointer type), and use `&PQ` in every other instance in `main`. Using an automatic variable for the priority queue is adequate in this instance.

Otherwise you need to *allocate memory* (using `malloc` &c.), assign the location of that memory to `PQ`, and remember to call `free` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The PriorityQueue Variable PQ does't have any memory space allocated for it, the reason for the segmentation fault is that you are trying to store variable in a unallocated space(or the memory location you have no authority to access). To get memory space for the variable PQ use the malloc() function.

```
PQ = (PriorityQueue*) malloc(sizeof(PriorityQueue));
```